# How to show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\ \exists! n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \leq n < x+1$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

To show that:
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\ \exists! n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ s.t. }x\leq n < x+1
$$
I know that the said $n$ is the infimum of the set of integers greater than or equal to $x$:
$$
n = \inf{ \{m:m\geq x , m \in \mathbb{Z}\}}
$$
Now, how do I show that this $n$ is less than $x+1$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what does "$\exists! n$" mean?

Comment: It means "there exists exactly one such $n.$"

Comment: Oh really? I have actually not seen that before...

Comment: @ananta Which axioms do we rely on? What we have to use or avoid to prove this proposition?

Answer (score 2):

If $n = \inf{ \{m:m\geq x , m \in \mathbb{Z}\}}\ \geq x+1,$ then $n-1\geq x,$ contradicting the minimality of $n$ (in the definition of $n$).

Comment: Of course this presupposes you know: \exists m \in  \mathbb Z, m \ge x$.

Comment: I find your comment strange: obviously such an $m$ exists…

Comment: Existence of such $m$ is usually proved from the Archimedian property of the reals.